# Where to put my custom functions in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am pulling my hair out.  I have created some simple functions that generate random numbers, pulled from a database that I want to use on wordpress pages. (And then call them from the theme files, such as header.php or page.php.)

I have tried putting the functions inside functions.php that is in the theme (as per the documentation I have read), but I keep getting the "call to undefined function" errors! What in the world am I doing wrong?

Example, here is a function inside the functions.php

```
function randomPollNumber() {
///this gets a random active poll number
    $sql12 = "SELECT id FROM poll WHERE removed = 0 AND active = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    $result12 = mysql_query($sql12);
    $myrow12 = mysql_fetch_row($result12);
    $pollquestionid = $myrow12[0];
    return $pollquestionid;
}
```

And I am calling it, from the header.php file with this

```
<?php echo randomPollNumber(); ?>
```

And yes, I DID try using the if_function_exists, but of course it cannot FIND the function, so of course it does not exist.  Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very strange - some debugging tips:

1. Put die('functions.php file loaded') statement at the beginning of functions.php (not inside a function). If it doesn't die, you know the file isn't being loaded.
2. If it dies, then check your spelling (copy and paste the function name from functions.php into your echo [...]). It's amazing how many times I'm SURE I've spelt it right, when in fact I haven't.
3. If it doesn't die, check that your file is definitely called functions.php, that it's definitely inside the right theme folder for the theme you are coding.
4. It's possible that the functions.php file has an error in it, and so is not being parsed, hence Wordpress can't find the function. Check your logs for errors. Load the functions file and nothing else, and check that the function is working. Are you using PHP Unit or something like that?

Comment: I thought you saved me Blowski! But alas, no.  I tried 1, it died. Did step 2, they matched. 3. Yep. functions. 4.  I loaded up JUST the function.php and alas, it had errors BEFORE my functions.  (Ironically, a function not exists for "add_action('admin_head', 'kubrick_theme_page_head');")  SO, i took it out...it ran perfectly....got excited.... tried it.... and same deal....Function does not exist!! GRRR. I appreciate the tips though and will keep them in mind for the future.  Oh, I have no idea what PHP Unit is....

Comment: @NarfFlarf: I don't know what Wordpress's error_reporting settings are by default, but try running `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` at the top of your `functions.php` file. If there's anything going wonky in that file, this should tell you what/where.

Comment: PHP unit just lets you test the functions by themselves to see that they are working. @AgentConundrum 's point is good too, though I would add it to the root index.php file and put ini_set('display_errors', '1'); in there as well. Adding it to the functions.php file will not return errors if they are happening before that file is loaded. Just make sure you remove the code again before you put the site live. One more thing - try removing any other code from the functions.php. Just have your function and nothing else.

Comment: Welp. Nuffin. :(   The only error I got for error reporting is "Strict Standards: is_a(): Deprecated."  And I tried only putting MY functions in there along with a fun ECHO just to see. It indeed loaded the echo.  I am at such a loss..... and I told my client this would be an easy one!!  Gotta love it, right?  lol  Maybe my template itself is.... doing something...?

Comment: @NarFlarf I know that it goes against best practice, but you can include the function inside the relevant template and then refactor it out to the functions.php file when you figure out what's wrong - at least your client will be happy. It still sounds like functions.php is not being loaded before header.php is parsed. Try using include_once "./functions.php" inside your header.php file, before the call to your custom function.

Comment: ha, great minds think alike!   I actually created my own functions file and included that. Works just fine. But I HAD to specify it as an abolute path, ie include('/home/path/to/file').   Why? No clue!  LOL.  Thank you for the help and troubleshooting with me.

Comment: The absolute path thing is usually a PHP restriction on shared hosting. You can get around by using `define(‘ABSPATH’, dirname(__FILE__).’/');require_once(ABSPATH.’functions.php’);`. Glad to know you got it working anyway.