# WordPress Query Posts for 10 latest posts only 2 per category

Tags: wordpress

I want to get latest x number of posts but only 2 from a single category. Is it possible through query posts. I can do that using posts loop anyway but would like to know if its possible through query posts method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) and write your own function to get what you need. 
It should work four you to query the posts from specific categories and merge them together into an array. Afterwards call the function in your template.

Also check the following [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667812/where-to-put-my-custom-functions-in-wordpress).

**UPDATE**
It is currently not possible to query the different types in on statement. Better would be to organize your posts. Have a look at [Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Consider adding a bit of example code to your answer to make it easier for people to understand.

Comment: I know about custom functions, but I wanted to know is, if there is anyway to get the posts using 1 database query instead of getting a bunch of posts and then filtering them out.

Comment: @Mgdls, I do not require to query different types. Let me rephrase my question with an example.
I have 2 categories, Headline and Exclusive. All I want is that I get latest 2 posts from both the categories but not 4 posts from 1 category as I currently get if i use order by date on posts.

Comment: Unfortunately you will need two queries, since you want two different taxonomies and want 2 post per taxonomy. Actually you can query two categories on one query, but can not specify to return 2 post per Taxonomy.

Comment: Actually you can filter the ressults with PHP and extract one from every taxonomy.